# Regex getting group from file

Tags: regex

My String looks like:

```
Especificação do Título

GRND3 - GRENDENE

GRND3 - GRENDENE

POSI3 - POSITIVO INF
```

I need to get GRND3, GRND3, POSI3 in 3 separated groups.

Is there any expression that i can do it easily?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Certainly. What have you tried? Which language or tool are you using? What do you mean by group?

Comment: @m.buettner: group==capture?

Comment: Before you can write a regular expression, you have to be able to describe, in English, the rules that you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with not specifying a specific language is that `^` can mean start of line or start of text.

**If `^` means start of line:**

```
"^(\w+) -"
```

should cover it. Then you get the first group (again language specific).

**If `^` means start of text (would also work in above case):**

There are different line separators on different systems, but generally this should work:

```
"\n(\w+) -"
```

and again get the first group.

Note that I'm assuming the string you want to get consists only of letters and numbers, in which case `\w+` (which means one or more (`+`) word characters (letter or number)) and this string is followed by a space then a `-`.

Not sure what you mean by "3 separated groups", you generally just loop through all the matches, but if you want to match them all in 1 regex, something like this should do it:

```
"\n(\w+) - (?:\w|\s)*\r?\n(\w+) - (?:\w|\s)*\r?\n(\w+) -"
```

though that's not pretty, is difficult to maintain and understand and is prone to error.